# SSE best way to set register to 0.0's and 1.0's?

Tags: c, math, assembly, vector, sse

I am doing some sse vector3 math.

Generally, I set the 4th digit of my vector to 1.0f, as this makes most of my math work, but sometimes I need to set it to 0.0f.

So I want to change something like:
(32.4f, 21.2f, -4.0f, 1.0f) to (32.4f, 21.2f, -4.0f, 0.0f)

I was wondering what the best method to doing so would be:

1. Convert to 4 floats, set 4th float, send back to SSE
2. xor a register with itself, then do 2 shufps
3. Do all the SSE math with 1.0f and then set the variables to what they should be when finished.
4. Other?

Note: The vector is already in a SSE register when I need to change it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if they came out with a version of SSE that worked on 3 scalars at a time!!

Comment: bit and with `0xfff..ff00000000`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your original vector is in xmm0:

```
; xmm0 = [x y z w]
xorps %xmm1, %xmm1         ; [0 0 0 0]
pcmpeqs %xmm2, %xmm2       ; [1 1 1 1] 
movss %xmm1, %xmm2         ; [0 1 1 1]
pshufd $0x20, %xmm1, %xmm2 ; [1 1 1 0]
andps %xmm2, %xmm0         ; [x y z 0]
```

should be fast since it does not access memory.

Comment: You can generate the mask faster by shifting the register of all-1s to leave the high dword with all-zeros, instead of `movss+pshufd`.  (`psrldq %xmm2, 4`, or `pslldq` to shift the other way and leave the low dword zeroed.).  Or if you can't spare a register, you could just keep the `[1 1 1 0]` mask for `andps` in memory.

Comment: Also, SSE4.1 `blendps` with a zeroed reg will let you put zeroes in the high element easily, with just two instructions (`xorps` and `blendps`).  But Jester's `pshufhw $0xa4` is really the best, as long as you're sure that the high element is really `1.0f` exactly, and thus has a zero word.

Comment: could you provide a version of this using compiler intrinsics?

Answer (score 5):

AND with a constant mask.

In assembly ...

```
myMask:
.long 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0x00000000

...
andps  myMask, %xmm#
```

where # = {0, 1, 2, ....}

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it without memory access, you could realize that the value 1 has a zero word in it, and the value zero is all zeroes. So, you can just copy the zero word to the other. If you have the 1 in the highest dword, `pshufhw xmm0, xmm0, 0xa4` should do the trick:

```
(gdb) ni
4       pshufhw $0xa4, %xmm0, %xmm0
(gdb) p $xmm0.v4_float
$4 = {32.4000015, 21.2000008, -4, 1}
(gdb) ni
5       ret
(gdb) p $xmm0.v4_float
$5 = {32.4000015, 21.2000008, -4, 0}
```

The similar trick for the other locations is left as an excercise to the reader :)

Answer (score 1):

[pinsrw](http://www.jaist.ac.jp/iscenter-new/mpc/altix/altixdata/opt/intel/vtune/doc/users_guide/mergedProjects/analyzer_ec/mergedProjects/reference_olh/mergedProjects/instructions/instruct32_hh/vc234.htm)?

Comment: For some reason GCC isn't letting me use "__builtin_ia32_pinsrw" intrinsic - any ideas?

Comment: Try: __builtin_ia32_pinsrw128

Comment: If memory serves, PINSRW is SSE4 and thus only available to processors that support it.

Answer (score -1):

Why not multiply your vector element wise with [1 1 1 0]? I'm pretty sure there is an SSE instruction for element wise multiplication.

Then to go back to a vector with a 1 in the 4th dimension, just add [0 0 0 1]. Again there is an SSE instruction for that, too.

Comment: But how do I get [1 1 1 0] into sse registers in fast way?

Comment: bitwise AND instead of multiply, bitwise OR instead of add.  And yeah, other than keeping those constants in memory, there's the problem of generating that value.